# fetching previous row in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help on creating the sql for this requirement - I have the data in a table :

```
Empid      Date         Deptid  Location
-----------------------------------------
001    1st Jan 2012    101      BC
002    4th Jan 2012    101      AB
003    6th Jan 2012    103      PQ
004    8th Jan 2012    104      AB
005    10th jan 2012   105      XY
```

Now I want to fetch the previous row (depending upon `date` field) where location is AB and dept value is different. in the above example the following row should be fetched

```
003    6th Jan 2012    103      PQ
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What language are you accessing the database with?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server 2005+

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT *

FROM(SELECT *,Row_Number() OVER(Order By [Date]) From <Your table>)X

WHERE X.[Date] = '8th Jan 2012' AND Location = 'AB')X WHERE Rn = Rn-1
```

Comment: thanks but i dont want to fetch based on row number concepts. besides the date cannot be hardcoded. I need to write a criteria where max(date) is < date where location is AB and dept of this row and of previous row is different

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `YOUR_TABLE`
WHERE `id` < (SELECT `id` FROM `YOUR_TABLE`
              WHERE `location` =  'AB'
              AND `deptid` =  '104') 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

May be this will help you :D

Answer (score 1):

```
create table tblTest (
  Empid char(3)
  ,Date date
  ,Deptid char(3)
  ,Location char(2)
);

insert into tblTest (Empid,Date,Deptid,Location) values ("001","2012/01/01","101","BC");
insert into tblTest (Empid,Date,Deptid,Location) values ("002","2012/01/04","101","AB");
insert into tblTest (Empid,Date,Deptid,Location) values ("003","2012/01/06","103","PQ");
insert into tblTest (Empid,Date,Deptid,Location) values ("004","2012/01/08","104","AB");
insert into tblTest (Empid,Date,Deptid,Location) values ("005","2012/01/10","105","XY");

SELECT
  t2.*
FROM
  tblTest t1
  LEFT JOIN tblTest t2 ON t1.Date<t2.date
                          AND
                          t1.Deptid <> t2.Deptid
WHERE
  t1.Empid = "002"
ORDER BY
  t2.Date
LIMIT 1;
```

[You can test on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f648/22/0)

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern. Actually I think I messed up the condition, which should be `LastAB.DeptID!=Emp.DeptID` but you get the idea. The subquery gives you the singular record that you want to start with. The outer query then finds the records of a prior date at a different Location (or DeptID or whatever condition you set) and uses ORDER BY + LIMIT 1 to pinpoint a single record.

```
select Emp.*
from Emp
join (
  select *
  from Emp
  where Location = 'AB'
  order by Date desc
  limit 1) LastAB on LastAB.Date>Emp.Date
                 and LastAB.Location!=Emp.Location
order by Emp.Date desc
limit 1;
```

Working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a39d0/3/0) replicated below

```
create table Emp (
  Empid char(3),
  Date datetime,
  Deptid int,
  Location char(2)
  );
insert Emp values
('001', '2012-01-01', 101, 'BC'),
('002', '2012-01-04', 101, 'AB'),
('003', '2012-01-06', 103, 'PQ'),
('004', '2012-01-08', 104, 'AB'),
('005', '2012-01-10', 105, 'XY');

--- result

EMPID   DATE    DEPTID  LOCATION
003     January, 06 2012   103  PQ
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name where Date < (select Date from table_name where Location="AB") and Deptid NOT IN( select Deptid from table_name where Location="AB") order by Date desc limit 1 ;
```

Returns the previous row based on Date field given that location is "AB" and also checks that the employee is not from the same department